# How to properly pass data from mongodb using callback when looping through multiple db.Phrase.find calls

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm receiving params from my get request that looks like this:

```
{ location: 'Venice', weather: 'Dry', what: 'Yoga', who: 'Bob' }
```

I then query a mongodb database that loops through each of the key and value pairs and queries for their union in the database.

I then save the returned values to outputCaption and then use a callback to pass the outputCaption back.

The problem is the callback gets called as many times as their key-value pairs looped over.

I'm forced to do this because I need the callback inside the db.Phrase.find call but I call that multiple times...

So I've fixed it using the code in app.get (I wait until all the keys have defined values in outputCaption before doing anything)

It works, but I can't imagine it's the best way to do it so I'm hoping there's a less hackish way?
Thanks

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./modules/db')
var logic = require('./modules/logic')

...

app.get('/phrase', function(req, res){
  logic(req.query, function(outputCaption){
    var flag = true
    for (key in outputCaption){
      if (outputCaption[key] === null){
        console.log('Incomplete')
        var flag = false;
      }
    }
    if (flag === true) {
      console.log(outputCaption);
    };
  });
})

...
```

logic.js

```
var db = require('./db')

var logic = function(params, callback){
  var outputCaption = {
    who: null, 
    what: null, 
    location: null, 
    weather: null
  };
  for (key in params){
    category = key.toLowerCase();
    option = params[key].toLowerCase();
    db.Phrase.find({$and: [
      {category: category}, 
      {option: option}
      ]}, function(err, phrases){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        var options = Object.keys(phrases).length
        var idxOfOptionPicked = Math.floor(Math.random() * options)
        outputCaption[phrases[idxOfOptionPicked].category] = phrases[idxOfOptionPicked].phrase
        callback(outputCaption)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = logic;
```

Comment: try submitting a help request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of firing multiple queries and performing a union of the result at the client side, make use of the query operators to allow `MongoDB` to do the union for you.

That way you:

- Avoid multiple hits to the database.
- Avoid multiple callback handlers.
- Can post process the results in a single callback handler.

You can modify your code to prepare a query object from the request parameter,

```
  var params = {location: 'Venice', weather: 'Dry', what: 'Yoga', who: 'Bob' };
  var query = {};
  var conditions = [];
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key){
   var $and = {};
   $and["category"] = key.toLowerCase();
   $and["option"] = params[key];
   conditions.push($and);
  });
  (conditions.length > 1)?(query["$or"] = conditions):(query = conditions[0]);
```

Now the constructed query looks like:

```
{ '$or': 
   [ { category: 'location', option: 'Venice' },
     { category: 'weather', option: 'Dry' },
     { category: 'what', option: 'Yoga' },
     { category: 'who', option: 'Bob' } 
   ] 
}
```

You can pass this object to the `find()` method, to get the results in a single hit:

```
db.Phrase.find(query,callback);
```

This way your code remains cleaner and easier to understand.